# Access workspace path programmatically in pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, workspace

I'm working with PyDev for eclipse to create python scripts that run unit tests.

How can I access the current Eclipse's workspace path programmatically?

Comment: I would really suggest against trying to write tests like this.  You'll be writing tests that can't be run from the terminal or even from another IDE.  What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. These scripts run tests on tools created on another platform, but share the same path.

Comment: If your tests use the PyDev workspace, they can't run outside of an environment with a workspace, aka PyDev.  There should be a very compelling reason to create such a dependency if you are going to do so, and I don't see one here.  Besides, why do you even need access to the workspace?  Config files or something?

Comment: Sort of. there are other (already built) applications that reside on the same file structure, i.e. within the same workspace or relative to it, which i need to run as part of the test.

Comment: Why can't you use `PYTHONPATH`, or `__file__` with `importlib` or `__import__` (or `subprocess` if you need to launch things on their own)?  Unless you are actually directly interacting with Eclipse as part of your app, there is almost certainly a more generic, flexible, and easy to use way to get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Actually this is a good idea. I originally wanted to have that path on the PyDev console, but thanks to your recommendation, I'll use the `__file__` in a module and just import it to the console. (can I set that comment as an answer?)